# Check if shell script is already running (feh) (i3)

Tags: shell, cron, cron-task, cronie

Inside my `~/Pictures/wallpapers/` folder I have a shell script that changes the wallpaper using a `while true` each time the `sleep` function terminates:

`feh-auto.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  feh /home/maruko/Pictures/wallpapers --randomize --bg-fill
  sleep 1800
done
```

this script is automatically run each time the laptop powers up, or the `i3` configuration is reloaded in place using the shortcut `Win+Shift+R`:

`~/.config/i3/config`

```
...
### CHANGE WALLPAPER RANDOMLY
# https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/set-background-wallpapers-on-i3wm
exec_always --no-startup-id ~/Pictures/wallpapers/feh-auto.sh
...
```

Making changes to the `i3` configuration is usually accompanied with a reload in place, so that said changes take place.

The problem is that **each time a reload occurs, a new instance of `feh-auto.sh` is also created**, meaning that now instead of 1 timer, I have multiple timers of 1800, that will change the wallpaper *x* times where *x* is the number of times I reloaded the configuration.

I would like a more appropriate behavior as I reload: check if `feh-auto.sh` is already running and if it is, do not create a new instance.

Could you please guide me to the best solution?

Thank you.

---

## EDIT

As @balki suggested in the comments, I have created a `cron` job

(`sudo crontab -e`)

```
@reboot /home/maruko/Documents/program-files/shell/feh-auto.sh
```

to run the following script

`feh-auto.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=0:0
feh /home/maruko/Pictures/wallpapers/ --randomize --bg-fill
```

However, when booting up or rebooting the system, the wallpaper is blank as if nothing really happened. The command `sudo systemctl status cronie.service` reports the following:

```
crond[3300]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
CROND[3307]: (root) CMD (/home/maruko/Documents/program-files/shell/feh-auto.sh)
CROND[3300]: (root) CMDOUT (feh ERROR: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?)
CROND[3300]: (root) CMDEND (/home/maruko/Documents/program-files/shell/feh-auto.sh)
CROND[3300]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
```

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: consider using `cron` or `systemd-timers`. If you want to go with your sleep solution, check `flock` to synchronise

Comment: @balki I've updated my question. I've followed your suggestion but encountered another problem. Could you look into it? Thank you.

Comment: Glad you found a solution with `i3`. But for cron solution, it does not work as it is running before display is set up. Adding a sleep would work I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this post is to **read documentation**:

`i3` config comes with the `exec` and `exec_always` commands:

`exec` will execute the command once at boot,

`exec_always` will execute the command on reloads too.

The solution is to substitute the above call to `feh-auto.sh`:

`~/.config/i3/config`

```
### START FEH WALLPAPER
# note: exec_always will run the script on each reload, not ideal
# --no-startup-id will eliminate the problem of loading icon on boot
exec --no-startup-id /home/maruko/Pictures/wallpapers/feh-auto.sh
```